# Get a grid to rotate on mouse drag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation

How do get a grid to rotate on mouse drag as it shows in the gif in WPF c#?

[image]

I've tried this code but I'm getting a very bad result and I do not have any idea how should I do the sizing.

```
    double angle = 30;
    Point oldPoint;
    Point newPoint;
    int d;
    RotateTransform transe = new RotateTransform();
    private void Border_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid b = sender as Grid;
       if (Mouse.Captured == b)
        {
            newPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(mu);    
            if (oldPoint.Y != newPoint.Y)
            {
                if (oldPoint.Y > newPoint.Y)
                    transe.Angle = (oldPoint.Y - newPoint.Y);
                else
                    transe.Angle += (newPoint.Y - oldPoint.Y);

                gt.RenderTransform = transe;
            }
            return;
        }
    }


    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_2(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid b = sender as Grid;
        if (Mouse.Captured != b)
        {
            oldPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(mu);
            Mouse.Capture(b);

        }
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { 
        oldPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        newPoint = new Point(0, 0);

        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
```

The contol in xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="mu" Height="90" Width="128" MouseUp="mu_MouseUp" MouseMove="Drase_MouseMove"
      Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="45" Cursor="Arrow" Background="White">

<Grid x:Name="gt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Background="Black" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mu, Mode=OneWay}"
      MouseMove="Border_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_2" 
      MouseLeftButtonUp="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp_1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
</Grid>
```

This is what I have managed to get so far. As you can see it's rotating uncontrollably.

[image]

Comment: Could you revise the code, clean unnecessary commented parts and give it some more context in relation with xaml?

Comment: I've removed the unused parts, and added the xaml of the code.

Comment: In case you already saw my answer before I edited it, I managed to get it working perfectly and have now updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach isn't quite right. Here's my working version of the code:

```
private void Border_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Grid b = sender as Grid;
    if (Mouse.Captured == b)
    {
        Point origin = new Point(mu.ActualWidth / 2, mu.ActualHeight / 2);
        var rawPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(mu);
        var transPoint = new Point(rawPoint.X - origin.X, rawPoint.Y - origin.Y);
        var radians = Math.Atan2(transPoint.Y, transPoint.X);
        var angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);
        transe.Angle = angle;
        gt.RenderTransform = transe;
    }
}
```

I'm not the best when it comes to the math, but I'll try to what I'm doing. The idea behind my code is that the angle of the rotate transform should always match the angle of the mouse relative to the vertical center-line of the `mu`.

`Point origin = new Point(mu.ActualWidth / 2, mu.ActualHeight / 2);` gives me the center of the `mu`, which is the mathematical origin point for the calculations.

`var transPoint = new Point(rawPoint.X - origin.X, rawPoint.Y - origin.Y);` translates the location of the mouse cursor so that it's relative to the center of `mu` (i.e. `origin`), as opposed to the top-left corner.

Then, stealing a bit of code I don't quite understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073086/5086631), I use [`Atan2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2) to calculate the angle.

Comment: Holy crap, yes u did it' and it's working. Thank you very much, you're my hero!!

Comment: @mohamedsherrif Ha, that comment made my day :) Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then.